# VStack spacing around image, but not around text

Tags: swiftui

I have the following code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("ContentView Header 1")
                .border(Color.green, width: 2)
            Text("ContentView Header 2")
                .border(Color.green, width: 2)
            Image(systemName: "arrow.up")
                .border(Color.green, width: 2)
            Text("ContentView Footer 1")
                .border(Color.green, width: 2)
        }
    }
}
```

The result looks as follows:

[image: vertical stack showing two texts, an image and another text, with space around the image]

Why is there spacing around the image, but not around the texts? It disappears when I explicitly set spacing for the `VStack`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> public struct VStack<Content> : View where Content : View {
>
>     /// Creates an instance with the given `spacing` and Y axis `alignment`.
>     ///
>     /// - Parameters:
>     ///     - alignment: the guide that will have the same horizontal screen
>     ///       coordinate for all children.
>     ///     - spacing: the distance between adjacent children, or nil if the
>     ///       stack should choose a default distance for each pair of children.
> ```

Last line - "stack should choose a **default distance for each pair of children**"

Comment: hey Asperi, did you really read all Apple definitions....? :D

Comment: That is fascinating. What is meant by "each pair of children"? I mean, why are the children (in this case, 3 Texts and 1 Image) considered "paired"? And do you know where I can find the default distance for each type?