# (1) How to eliminate the space between a text and a list; (2) different products in canvas and simulater

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to eliminate the space (circled red in my screen shot).  I brute forced it by adding a negative value in .padding.  It's fugly but it does the job....but only in the canvas.  For some reason in the simulator it doesn't work.

Originally I put the "+" and "-" in two separate .nevigationbartitle after the Lists. For reasons beyond me, it only shows the first one.

Self learning novice here.  All help appreciated. Thanks

[image: screenshot]

> struct ListView: View {

```
@State var items: [String] = [
    "The item here can be deleted",
    "You can also double tap the item to perform action",
    "test"
]

var body: some View {
    
    HStack {
        VStack {
            Text("+")
                .onLongPressGesture {
                    print("long press")
                }
                .onLongPressGesture {
                    print("long press")
                }
                .font(.system(size: 60))
                .padding(.bottom, -25)
                .zIndex(1)
                .foregroundColor(.green)
            
            List{
                    ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                        Text("\(item)")
                    }
                    .font(.system(size: 10.0))
            }
            .environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 8)
            
        }
        VStack {
            Text("-")
                .onTapGesture (count: 2){
                    print("double tap")
                }
                .onLongPressGesture {
                    print("long press")
                }
            List{
                ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                    Text("\(item)")
                }
                .font(.system(size: 10.0))
            }
            .environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 8)
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Use `VStack(spacing: 0) {`  and read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/59677042/12299030

Comment: @Asperi Thanks. But unfortunately, it doesn't work....  (screenshot https://imgur.com/a/KeHyPAs )

Comment: That is inside List itself, due to default grouped based layout. If you don't like it change style to plain or inset.